# Easy way to grab the last comment on an issue in a jql query

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

Is there an out of the box way to query the last comment on an issue in Jira. Customer wants to only see the latest comment - and itt not clear there is a JQL function to do this or a way to extend this as an admin.

Example:
Select project = '123' and requester = 'Smith' **and comment > previous comment etc and not blank etc**

Is there a plug in to do this or workflow process?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.

JQL has no such functionality. You will need a third party add-on like Scriptrunner to provide that functionality.